# GaussJordan elimination Algorithm Java

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, linear-algebra

I have some trouble with my Gauss Jordan elimination method. It looks a bit oversimplified but on paper it should work. It sets the pivot to 1 considering that in case of 0 it must perform a swap. Then it subtracts that row times the value conindex  of the remaing rows with the same index number of the pivot column.

I use these methods in my final algorithm.

Row multiplication:

```
public static double[] rowMul(double[] row, double scalar) {
    BigDecimal[] temp = new BigDecimal[row.length];
    BigDecimal s = new BigDecimal(scalar);
    double[] newrow = new double[row.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = new BigDecimal(row[i]).multiply(s);
        newrow[i] = temp[i].doubleValue();
    }
    return newrow;
}
```

Dividing rows:

```
public static double[] rowDiv(double[] row, double divisor) {
    BigDecimal[] temp = new BigDecimal[row.length];
    BigDecimal s = new BigDecimal(divisor);
    double[] newrow = new double[row.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = new BigDecimal(row[i]).divide(s);
        newrow[i] = temp[i].doubleValue();
    }
    return newrow;
}
```

Row subtraction:

```
public static double[] subtractRow(double[] mat1, double[] mat2) {
    double[] c = new double[mat1.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < mat1.length; i++) {
        c[i] = mat1[i] - mat2[i];
    }
    return c;
}
```

Pivot check and row swap:

```
public static boolean checkPivot(double[][] mat, int row) {
    if (mat[row][row] == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
// Keeps track of the number of swaps performed to secure a finite solution.
private static int swapcount = 0;

// Mind giving the index value. So row starting from 0 up instead of 1!
public static double[][] swapRow(double[][] mat, int row) {
    swapcount++;
    if (swapcount >= mat.length - row) {
        System.out.println("no possible combinations.");
        swapcount = 0;
        return mat;
    }
    double[] temp = mat[row];
    for (int i = row; i < mat.length - 1; i++) {
        mat[i] = mat[i + 1];
    }
    mat[mat.length - 1] = temp;
    if (checkPivot(mat, row) == true) {
        mat = swapRow(mat, row);
    }
    swapcount = 0;
    return mat;
}
```

And then my final Gauss Jordan Algorithm:

```
public static double[][] gaussJordan(double[][] matrix) {
    double[][] mat = matrix;
    int m = mat.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        if (checkPivot(mat, i) == true) {
            mat = swapRow(mat, i);
        }
        mat[i] = rowDiv(mat[i], mat[i][i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (j == i) {
                j++;
            } else {
                mat[j] = subtractRow(mat[j], rowMul(mat[i], mat[j][i]));
            }
        }
    }
    return mat;
}
```

How ever if I give it this matrix to compute.

```
private static double[][] elim = {
    {-20,-10,10,-10},
    {  0, 10,-5, 10},
    {-10, 10,15, 20}
};
```

It somehow skips the middle column of the square 3 x 3 matrix on the left and returns.

```
1.0 0.375 0.0 0.625 
0.0 1.75  0.0 2.25 
0.0 1.5   1.0 2.5
```

The expected outcome is:

```
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.14286
0.0 1.0 0.0 1.28571
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.57143
```

Can somebody help me with finding that what I must have overlooked. I just hope its nothing to obvious! I thank you for your trouble.

Comment: Please include the expected outcome

Comment: I haven't got an answer to your question, but you seem to be mixing `double` and `BigDecimal` in a rather odd way. The problem with trying to do algebra with either of these types is that neither can represent simple fractions like 1/3 exactly, so row operations that are supposed to give you `0` actually don't. I'd advise trying to find an implementation of rational numbers.

Comment: I must admit it was something that was troubling me somewhat. And I think I know a way to implement rational numbers, specifically in the divide method. However somehow it doesn't feel like what's causing this specific problem. Nonetheless I'm going to take your advise to heart. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

`mat[j] = subtractRow(mat[j], rowMul(mat[i], mat[j][i]));`

seems wrong. With it new value of mat[j][i] is mat[j][i] - (mat[i][i] * mat[j][i]) which is != 0.

I think it should be

`mat[j] = subtractRow(mat[j], rowMul(mat[i], mat[j][i] / mat[i][i]));`

With it new value of mat[j][i] is mat[j][i] - (mat[i][i] * mat[j][i] / mat[i][i]) which is in fact 0.

Also:

`if (mat[row][row] == 0) {`

This is risky with doubles. I would advise something like Math.abs(mat[row][row]) < 1e-9

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I'm going to look in to it!

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, especially the                           if (mat[row][row] == 0) {                                 alteration was something I hadn't considered. However mat[i][i] should allready be 1 at that stage so I don't see what you mean by adding that division? Could you please clarify a bit more? Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, I've missed mat[i] = rowDiv(mat[i], mat[i][i]);.

Comment: At this point I've got nothing else. To be honest I'v never seen a version in which you iterate for(i=0; ..) for(j=0; ..). I've always used for(i=0; ..) for(j=i+1; ..). The result is a triangular matrix. Then I did a second sweep but with different loops: for(i=n-1; i>=0; i--) for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--) to get the diagonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks man, you know what you helped me a lot! I went with your method of the "double sweep" as it where and it works! A perfect outcome. Cheers!!